# Comparison of categorical percentages

Tags: categorical-data, percentage

I apologize if this has been asked, but I couldn't seem to find an answer anywhere.  I have two sets of data.  Each is made up of 5 categories.  These categories are ordinal as they are a 5 point Likert scale of sentiment from very negative to very position. Unfortunately, I do not have frequency information for each of these categories, but rather, percentages.  Is there an appropriate test that I could apply to compare these two data sets? This is the first time where I've run into a situation in which I only have percentages for a category instead of the raw frequencies.

Comment: I presumed the 5 categories are not ordered but independent. Is that right?

Comment: Wow yea, I should have said they are ordinal.  They are essentially sentiment from very negative to very positive.

Comment: This is very important and I think you should edit and clarify this in the question itself.

Comment: You mean you don't know how many subjects were in both data set ? By raw frequencies, do you mean counts ?

Comment: Your data structure is not clear. You have 2 sets of data with 5 categories each. Does that means this is a table with 5 rows and 2 columns (each value being a percent for that row and sum of columns is 100)? It will be helpful if you can post here some sample data.